# Access Mac OS X File Label Status (Red/Orange/Yellow, etc) with Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, file, label

Mac OS X Finder allows users to "Label" files and directories as Red, Orange, Yellow, etc.

How can I access this status from a Ruby script?

I need to find all files labeled "Red" in a named directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the xattr gem to access those

http://rubygems.org/gems/xattr

Comment: Almost, but  "Xattr.new( path_for_red_label_file ).get( "com.apple.FinderInfo" )" returns an empty string